# Is it possible to create a lock free SNAPSHOT transaction in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to basically create a fast, temporary, "fork" of a database (like a snapshot transaction) without any locks given that I know for a fact that the changes will never be committed and always be rolled back.

**Details:**
I'm currently working with SQL Server and am trying to implement a feature where the user can try all sorts of stuff (in the application) that is never persisted in the database.

My first instinct was to (mis)use snapshot transactions for that to basically "fork" the database into a short lived (under 15min) user-specific context. The rest of the application wouldn't even have to know that all the actions the user performs will later be thrown away (I currently persist the connection across requests - it's a web application).

Problem is that there are situations where the snapshot transaction locks and waits for other transactions to complete. My guess is that this happens because SQL server has to make sure it can merge the data if one of the open transactions commits, but in my case I know for a fact that I will never commit the changes from this transactions and always throw the data away (note that not everything happens in this transactions, there are other things that a user can do that happen on a different connection and are persisted).

Are there other ideas, that don't involve cloning the database (too large/slow) or updating/changing the schema of all tables (I'd like to avoid "poisoning" the schema with the implemenation detail of the "try out" feature).

Comment: The cleanest way to do this is arguably to have an in-memory database or LocalDB instance where users are free to do whatever they please without ever impacting live data. Even if what you asked for was somehow possible (and it's not, since at the very least taking schema locks is unavoidable), it would be really easy to slip up somewhere and end up with changes that were supposed to be thrown away, or for the user to get confused by changes made by other transactions. Also, the engine is strongly optimized for committing transactions, with rollback being expensive, so it doesn't scale well.

Comment: Schema locks would be fine I guess. The in-memory database also crossed our minds, problem is that the situation is not that straight forward. In the DB are a lot of, let's call it "items", you fully own some of them - all changes to those are persisted, some of them are readonly, you can't change those. And there is also a "try-me" item (shared between all users) with is "owned" by an NPC, with most features read-only and/or faked. With this new feature request we are basically trying to "split" users into their own consistent world only for this single "try-me" item.

Answer (score 0):

No.  SQL Server has [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) [Database Snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), but the snapshots are read-only.  So where a SNAPSHOT transaction acquires regular exclusive locks when it modifies the database, a Database Snapshot would just give you an error.

There are storage technologies that can a writable copy-on-write storage snapshot, like NetApp.  You would run a command to create a new LUN that is a snapshot of an existing LUN, present it to your server as a disk, mount its volume in a folder or drive letter, and attach the files you find there as a database.  This is often done for cloning across environments to refresh dev/test with prod data without having to copy all the data.  But it seems like way too much infrastructure work for your use case.